# ruby: each row in leaflet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet

I have one table called "posts" and two column lat/lng in sqlite.
I just want to show it in leaflet map. 
I tried the loops *each do*

***in testleaflet.html.erb***

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
L.marker([<%=@post.lat%>,<%=@post.lng %>]).addTo(map);
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately I only see the last entered values(lat/lng) in the map.
how can I do?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `@post` to `post` as you are lopping through `@posts` as `post`

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  L.marker([<%=post.lat%>,<%=post.lng %>]).addTo(map);
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok ... small distraction, now it's okay!